# Checklist with workflow and timer

Tags: windows, calendar, workflow, outlook, task-management

I am looking for some advice on software. I currently set up meetings and I have a checklist that is currently in Word. There are many steps with many moving pieces to ensure these meetings are ready to go. With trying to organize 3-4 different meetings at the same time, it gets a little confusing.

I have been researching and know that I will have to set up some sort of workflow system but not sure if what I am researching to do is possible. What I need is to set up an email list and the meeting schedule and be able to check it off on the list and it would send calendar invites to all the parties involved. I am also looking to have a timer to send out reminder email templates for 3 months out, 1 month out, 4 weeks, and so on and that it would check off that task once complete.

This would help me focus more on the manual items that can not be automated and having a mess of reminders in my calendar to check the checklists and send out the next step.

I am currently working with Windows 7 and it is with a big corporation. The software does not have to be free, but a free trial would be nice to try and set things up. I have looked into the Microsoft Flow in Office 365 but it doesn't integrate with Planner. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wunderlist - https://www.wunderlist.com/ seems to be a tool that should satisfy your requirements. It has an integration with outlook so that you can throw elements in and sort them out and has a support for sharing with team/sending out reminders.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will look into this